-bash: jeprof: did not found command
When I am using this command to install jeprof like this:
yum install gperftools-devel -y

the command runs success and install the gperftools-devel-2.7-6.el8.x86_64, but when I use this command to show the tool:
jeprof --version

shows did not found the command. Am I missing something? I also tried like this:
sudo yum install gperftools -y


jeprof is provided by the jemalloc-devel package (available in the EPEL repository)

If you're looking for a particular command on CentOS (or any system that uses yum/dnf for package management), just run:
yum install /path/to/command

E.g.:
yum install /usr/bin/jeprof

This will locate and install the appropriate package (assuming that the path is correct and is provided by some package).
